# LocalNotification badge shows wrong Number in iOS7

Tags: ios, badge, localnotification

I have built a test-application for local notifications. it looks like this

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"My Next Custom Notification";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Second One Now";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    NSLog(@"Notifications: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
```

My AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

It works fine when I'm in Background or in the LockScreen I'm getting these notifications.

But when the first notifications comes in, it does not show the badge which should be "1" now. When the Second notification comes in the the badge shows "1" and not "2"(which would be the right number now). So what is wrong with my code?

Comment: hi your badge set when you register your notification .like, when you register notification that time badge 0 and you add + 1, thats why the badge display one . if want to add next than u put no 2 when registration time .Thanks and try it.

Comment: i can't get this to work. Can you post an code example, please?

Comment: Try application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

Comment: Check out the answer I had given below it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a simple mistake that you are scheduling the notification first than setting its badge number. So you should first set the notification badge number then schedule it.

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"My Next Custom Notification";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Second One Now";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
NSLog(@"Notifications: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
```

Also for the right badge number during the second notification either you should save your notification badge number or set it from the last notification badge as I had did in above code. Because in your code it just set the badge number from the current [UIApplication sharedApplication] badge which is 0 + 1 equals 1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"My Next Custom Notification";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =  1; //first notification 

    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Second One Now";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2; // second notification 

    NSLog(@"Notifications: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
```

after you add condition check first is fire then `cancelallnotification` and register remaining with decreasing badge order.

Comment: So.. this does not work,. When the first notification comes in, the bade does not increase its number. The same behavior like bevor.

Comment: its work when u did not see fist `notification`.if u see first one then set `cancelallnotificaton` and `regiaster` again second one for badge no 1.